# AJAX PHP HTML form questions

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am working on a order form for sandwiches. The four input fields indicate the quantity of the product. (Brown, white bread etc.)

I am looking for suggestions on how to "live" display the products with quantity and price on the bottom of that page.. Also i want to calculate totals. AJAX looks the best way in my opinion; but where do i start?

At this moment the products are static inside html, is it wise to use xml for that? (mysql is not a option at the moment)

I hope this question makes some kind of sense, and will give me some possibilities.

[image: form example]

Comment: Do you need to save 'live displayed' values or just need to display them at bottom?

Comment: Eventually yes. I want to display them live so the customers can see what they order. But i also need that data for the payment and mailing the overview of ordered sandwiches to the kitchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you think so you get to have any idea?
A simple example ok? :)
Live: http://jsfiddle.net/WPxgF/

Html:

```
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product<td>
        <td>Price<td>
        <td>Qtd<td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>Sandwich<td>
        <td class="price">3.00<td>
        <td class="quant"><input type="text" size="4" value=""/><td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
        <td>Juice<td>
        <td class="price">1.50<td>
        <td class="quant"><input type="text" size="4" value=""/><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total<td>
        <td><input type="text" size="4" id="amount" value=""/><td>
        <td><input type="text" size="4" id="quant" value=""/><td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".quant input").blur(function(){

            var amount = 0;

            var quant = 0;
            $(".quant input").each(function() {
                var thisQ = this.value;
                quant += Number(thisQ);
                var price = $(this).closest("tr").find(".price").html();
                amount += calcTot(thisQ, price);
            });
            $("#quant").val(quant);
            $("#amount").val(amount);

            $(".price").each(function() {
                price += Number($(this).html());
            });

        });

    });

    function calcTot(quant, price){

        var tot = quant * price;
        return tot;

    }
```

Comment: This looks like what i mean, is it perhaps possible to show the products you choose? And will this sample be "POST-able" to php?

Comment: Dont understand. Can you explain better?

Comment: It is also important that you can see the product on the bottom of that page on which you filled in the quantity. And i want to know if it will be possible to post the form/order with php.

Comment: Look now: http://jsfiddle.net/h2Wt9/ The details will now your creativity and necessity. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will be very usefull! Will it also be possible to display the specific kind of sandwich? Because different types of bread have also their own price)Like: 
White sandwich - cheese - 6x - €15
Baguette - salami - 4x - €14

Comment: Yes. The additional infos, is good you insert according to your need. The heavy coding are ready.  :)

Comment: I ask this because my javascript skills are not good enough to perform this action